# java httpServer Post request work

Tags: java, http

I'm start learning java programming, and I want make a simple server application. I read about  **com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer** and find a good example on this link: https://github.com/imetaxas/score-board-httpserver-corejava.

I understand how to do *Get-request* in url, but I don't know how POST works. I think it must be sent a form or data on the server.

I attach the link of project, which I'm learning, in readme the author wrote  *http://localhost:8081/2/score?sessionkey=UICSNDK* - it's not working...

1. I wrote in url and get sessionkey: "localhost:8081/4711/login --> UICSNDK"
2. I wrote in url this for Post request: "localhost:8081/2/score?sessionkey=UICSNDK" - not working and in chrome return 404 bad request
   3.wrote in url this:"localhost:8081/2/highscorelist"

Please help me, I am beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between GET and POST is that with a GET request the data you wish to pass to the endpoint is done by modifying the url itself by adding parameters to it.

With a POST any data you wish to send to the endpoint must be in the body of the request.

The body of a request is arbitrary data that comes after a blank line in the header The reqiest has the request line, following by any number of header attributes, then a blank line.

The server would need to know what the format of the body of the request was and parse it as appropriate.

Of course 'modern' frameworks like jax-rs allow you to automatically convert request data to objects, so that it is much simpler.

Comment: thanks for answer, but what's mean "must be in the body of the request"?If you aren't busy please write an example or give a link.

Comment: can I write Post request in url like Get?

Comment: could anyone help me? please

Comment: _any_ web request is just a bunch of bytes being sent to a socket. The contents of the web request follows the http standards. See http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_HTTPRequestMessageFormat.htm

Comment: thank you, nice explanation, I understood and  I found a program called fiddler. Now I can do a POST requests, I figure out that post request has a body.